# How to get number of options in Combo Box in SSJS?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I've tried getComponent("ComboBoxID").getChildCount() but that appears to not return the correct number. Anyone know if there is a method I can use? Or maybe a function needs to be created?

*EDIT* - And is there a way to loop through the options and get the values like in CSJS?:

for (var i = 1; i < comboBox.options.length; i++){
    pmtPlan = comboBox.options[i].value;
    ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this XSnippet can help:
http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=get-selectable-values-of-a-component

Instead of printing the selectable value(s) you have to count them.

Hope this helps

Sven

Comment: Thanks Sven. That got me what I needed.